# Rakefile Parameter substitution in teamcity

Tags: rake, teamcity-7.1

I'm trying to pass a standard teamcity build parameter `vcsroot.url` as the parameter of a rake task, using Teamcity's built in Rake build step.  However, the build parameter doesn't seem to be evaluated.

In the "Rake Tasks" box, I've got:

```
setup_github_pages["%vcsroot.url%"]
```

When I run this build I get the following error:

```
[Execute setup_github_pages] NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Yet on the build results parameter tab, I see the correct value for the `vcsroot.url` parameter.

Are there rules about which build step fields do / don't have parameter substitution performed? Or is there an escape sequence required (I've scoured the teamcity docs in vain...)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a custom environment variable to expose the configuration variable you're trying to access:

Reference [Teamcity and Rake: Where are the tc system properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275056/teamcity-and-rake-where-are-the-tc-system-properties)

For example, you want to pass system.CUSTOM property defined in the agent.conf file. Click the Add new variable link, specify CUSTOM as a name and %system.CUSTOM% as a value. Now in the rakefile you can access it as ENV['CUSTOM'].

I've been able to access vcsroot.url directly from within the rake task using this approach.